# Dynamically generate collada files

Tags: python, kml, google-earth, collada

Hello from what i understand that using Python i can dynamically send kml data to Google earth client. i was wondering is this possible for collada files? i need it in combination to load models in Google earth. so far i can do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, you would probably do it by creating a KML NetworkLink file that loads a KMZ that contains a KML file that points to a .dae file that is collada. That can all be autogenerated from Python. There are libraries to generate it or you can roll your own. Just search generate collada python and you'll find some resources that will work for you.